# Prior to the 1996 Basel Accords, how did banks measure market risk?

Tags: financial-economics

Basel Accord amendment was brought into effect in 1998.

One of the features were:

Allows banks to use proprietary in-house models for measuring market risks

How were market risks measured before this, and why did they feel the need to amend it?